# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SWRevealViewController revealToggel:]

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

I am following an Apple tutorial on creating an iOS Application using Swift [Developing iOS Apps (Swift)], and I have followed each step exactly as it is. This app has been running flawlessly in the Simulator, but suddenlly it started throwing a SIGABRT error (I made a short research to understand what a SIGABRT (Signal Abort) error is, and I've even found some other answers, but no one seems to fix my problem).

Console Output:

```
2017-10-25 02:00:23.553 myApplication[1358:48276] -[SWRevealViewController revealToggel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff74c813400
2017-10-25 02:00:23.824 myApplication[1358:48276] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SWRevealViewController revealToggel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff74c813400'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a39ae65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109e11deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3a348d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2f090a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2f04b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010a973194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ad747b7 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 152
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a973194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010aae26fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010aae29c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010aae2b43 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 690
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010aae1af8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e249b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e31d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010a991b66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a96bd97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2c6a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2bc95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2bbe13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2bb828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f092ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010a971610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  myApplication                       0x00000001098f224d main + 109
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d2c392d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: check all outlet connection.

Comment: i have checked all of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo? Should be `revealToggle`...

Comment: I guess I picked a wrong reason. SO posts are supposed to apply to other people's cases. A comment is well enough to help.

Comment: @LucasHuang That's not true. SO answers are supposed to answer the question; questions shouldn't be answered in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled `revealToggel:`. It should be `revealToggle:`.

Comment: That's what I said. My answer got deleted though since it "does not provide an answer to the question". I hope destiny is with you... :)